# Using Node and MySQL, how to select rows from Table A for a specific user ID(Table B)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

When a user triggers the GET /tasks function, I need the function callback to select all the tasks that belong to that user, using that user's User_ID and the respective Task_ID(s). Since the Tasks table isn't directly connected to the User's table (Courses in between), I'm not sure how to pull off this query correctly.

Please see the screenshot I have attached of the entity relationship diagram to get a better understanding of what I mean.

[Entity Relationship Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lJW1.png)

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
       host: "localhost",
       user: "root",
       password: "PASSWORD",
       database: "DATABASE"
   });

connection.connect(function(err) {
   if (err) {
       console.log("Your connection to the database failed \n");
       throw err;
   } else {
       console.log("Your connection to the database was successful \n")
   }
});

app.get("/tasks/:Task_Id", function(req, res) { // is :/Task_Id correct ?
   const taskId = req.params.Task_ID; // do I also need to define and use req.params.User_ID ?
   let select = "SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE"; // need help finishing this query

   connection.query(select, function(err, rows, fields) {
       if (err) {
           console.log("The query for tasks items failed");
           res.sendStatus(500);
           throw err;
       } else {
           console.log("The query for task items was successful");
           res.sendStatus(200);
           res.json(rows);
       }
       connection.end();
   });
});
```

Comment: If you wanna have the task for the specified userId, so use userId instead of taskId, and do your query depending of the userId. It's a lack a knowledge in sql query after, but ill will be something like `WHERE userId = ${userId}`

Comment: I figured it out; I have to use SQL Join() to combine information from two tables or more, in this case for my Users, Courses, and Tasks.

Comment: One suggestion would be to use an appropriate ORM Mr. As I see you're new at programming... Take a look at Sequelize for exemple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making the URL accept only `Task_Id`, You can get User_Id either by modifying the URL params `(/:Task_Id/:User_Id)` or by accepting the `User_Id` in **URL query** Like this

```
app.get("/tasks/:Task_Id", function(req, res) { 
   const User_Id = req.query.uid;
   //... Rest of the code ...
})
```

**Note: Must send the uid in URL like this** `>> url.com/tasks/taskid?uid="userid goes here"`